Expected welfare log-normal
I am reading a paper that assumes that individuals just consume their income and that welfare is $y^{1-\gamma} / 1-\gamma$, and they focus on the case where $\gamma>1$. If income is log-normally distributed, the we can write
$$
\frac{1}{1-\gamma} e^{\ln \left(y^{1-\gamma}\right)}=\frac{1}{1-\gamma} e^{-(\gamma-1) \ln (y)}
$$
And they say that "the standard constant absolute risk aversion calculations follow to derive a linear mean-variance frontier", so they conclude that then expected welfare is equivalent to $E(\ln y)-0.5(\gamma-1) V(\ln y)$. I'm not sure how the expression for expected welfare is retrieved. Thank you very much.

This might only be a partial answer.
Let $z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then it is known that see here:
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^z) = e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}
$$
Assume that $y$ is lognormal distributed, so $\ln(y) \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then,
$$
(1-\gamma) \ln(y) \sim N((1-\gamma) \mu, (1-\gamma)^2 \sigma^2).
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(u(y)) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{y^{1 - \gamma}}{1 - \gamma}\right),\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{e^{(1 - \gamma)\ln(y)}}{1 - \gamma}\right),\\
&= \frac{1}{1 - \gamma} \mathbb{E}\left(e^z\right) \text{ where } z = (1-\gamma)\ln(y) \sim N((1-\gamma) \mu, (1-\gamma)^2 \sigma^2),\\
&= \frac{1}{1 - \gamma} e^{(1 - \gamma)\mu + \frac{1}{2}(1-\gamma)^2 \sigma^2},\\
&= \frac{\exp\left((1 - \gamma)\left[\mu - (\gamma - 1)\sigma^2/2\right]\right)}{1 - \gamma},
\end{align*}
$$
This is as far as I got.
Note that,
$
\mu - (\gamma - 1) \sigma^2/2 = E(\ln(y)) - 0.5 (\gamma - 1) V(\ln(y))$.
